# How can you read a file as binary, hexadecimal or integer data for immediate data processing in PHP

Tags: php, binary, hex, bit-manipulation, data-processing

I have stumbled across a really odd issue in PHP that I thought would have been solved a very long time ago but doesn't seem to be.

I am reading a file of a proprietary format, byte by byte using

```
$handle = fopen("myfile.bin", "rb");

while (!feof($handle) && $pointer < $bytesToRead){
    $c = fread($handle, 1);
    $pointer ++;

    if($c == 0xff){
        echo "Desired functionality";
    }
}
```

But the issue I have is that `fread($handle, 1)` produces data in string format even though it knows I am reading a single byte of data.

Can I read it into a variable as an integer immediately so I can perform logical operations like `$c == 0xff` or `$c == 0b11111111`?

I'm running into a ridiculous usage of memory because I have to convert each byte read into a char array, convert those chars into integers and then perform my bitwise operators which involve rotation in that format. Then for readable output I have to go back to strings and chars with other odd functions in PHP which were introduced in 5.4

It all seems very weird.

Comment: Why can't you cast straight as an int? Use (int)fgetc($handle) to get the integer value of a single character? (So long as you have feof checking for EOF, then this should be fine).

Comment: This always returns int(0). I assume this is a result of a type issue in the background where characters are looked at internally as `0x{ascii code}` and the zero might have precedence.

Comment: Sorry - I'm being silly. Should have mean "ord". `ord(fgetc($handle))`. Not int. Doh.